# Create new object or reuse old object Java

Tags: java, oop

I have a HashMap of "buttons" which can be clicked with the key being the location (x and y coordinates) of the button. Every time new data is received from the database the buttons rearrange themselves and update their positions in the map and other values associated with the "button" object. Currently I have buttons as an immutable object so new buttons need to be created each time I receive new data.

When I thought of a real life example of this (buying a new, different colour version of your house instead of painting the one you already have) it seemed a bit wasteful to keep creating objects instead of just reusing the old ones, is this the best way to do it?

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing. Object creation *could* be the least expensive operation out of what you are doing. Or it could be the most. Hard to say. If buttons are cheap, go ahead make new ones.

Comment: First of all, I do not understand why it is closed. How is it a broad question? Probably beacuse people find it too difficult to think. Eitherway I think smomeone trying to answer it also have to think of the garbage collection part. It has a lot more to do if you create objects all the time. On the other hand stored objects are definitely there taking up memory all the time. Also I think the latter might lead you into storing objects that where not neccassary to store as a developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating new objects usually means allocating new memory, an operation that is quite expensive and something which should be avoided if a function really needs to be optimized.

It's hard (if not impossible) to say if it will be faster to create new objects or not in your specific case without any code. If we're talking about a list of 10 buttons it wont matter, but if we're talking about a list of trillions on buttons, you should probably try to reassign their values instead.

Below is a small example that illustrates the difference between creating new objects and reassigning a single value of an instance, if I understood you question correctly it should be somewhat similar to your case. The output on my machine can be seen below.

```
package org.stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Example {

    public static class MyObject {

        private double value;

        public MyObject(double value) {
            this.setValue(value);
        }

        public final void setValue(double value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public double getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = 0;
        ArrayList<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
            objects.add(new MyObject(Math.random()));
        }
        System.out.println("Time to create 1.000.000 objects: "
                + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis() - start)
                + " ms.");

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
            objects.get(i).setValue(Math.random());
        }
        System.out.println("Time to reassign 1.000.000 objects: "
                + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis() - start)
                + " ms.");

    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Time to create 1.000.000 objects: 323 ms.
Time to reassign 1.000.000 objects: 31 ms.
```